# drop columns and rows in one line in pandas

Tags: pandas, methods

I want to drop a range of rows and columns of a dataframe, I did it as follow:

```py
df.drop(df.columns[3:], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.index[3:], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Can I do the two processes in one method instead of two? 
Or is there any more sufficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you do this:

```py
df = df.iloc[:3, :3]
```

It returns the same thing as your code.